# Change NavBar color for all the pages in ionic

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, navbar

I am new in ionic and wants to learn it. my question is How to change nav bar color for all the pages in ionic 3.

I have been using following code

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar color="primary">
    <button ion-button menuToggle>
      <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
    </button>
    <ion-title>Hello Ionic</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
```

Is there any way to change nav bar color for all the pages instead of manually doing `<ion-navbar color="primary">`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Add following line to variables.scss file to change the color globally.

```
$toolbar-background: #3D9BDD;
```

Comment: how can we change the navbar text color?

Comment: In my case this parameter also sets the text `color` to the background color. Both attributes has the same color. `background` and `color`. Results in invisible text. If the color of the component is not set. -.- Is there also a text color variable? Btw. there are no docs about this. I have to check the sources. Ok, I found `$toolbar-text-color`. But not tested. In my case something is weird. ...

Answer (score 2):

This can achieve different way i will show you 2 way

**First way**

In **variables.scss** file **$colors** portion add customColor

```
$colors: (
  primary:    #488aff,
  secondary:  #32db64,
  danger:     #f53d3d,
  light:      #f4f4f4,
  dark:       #222,
  customColor:(
    base: #00953B,
    contrast: #ffffff
  )
);
```

Here base is background color and contrast is text-color

And change in .html file

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar color="customColor">
    <button ion-button menuToggle>
      <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
    </button>
    <ion-title>Hello Ionic</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
```

**Second way**

override default color toolbar color

```
$toolbar-background: #00953B;
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is looking for a solution using dynamic themes, it is possible to change the text color using css like this in Ionic 3:

```
.header .toolbar-title {
    color: #fff !important;
}
```