# ionic framework changing color navbar

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, frameworks, ionic3

I have some issue on change base color
Here is my code

```
<ion-header >
  <ion-navbar color="base_color">
    <button ion-button menuToggle>
      <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
    </button>
    <ion-title> {{ company_name }} </ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
```

I want to assign value to `base_color` example color code: `#BA5B0D`
    but it does not working. `base_color` it comes from .ts file my `variable` 
    Please anyone could help me 
    thanks for your help

Comment: Try this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49231296/change-navbar-color-for-all-the-pages-in-ionic/49231761#49231761

Answer (score 1):

> You can override scss variable in ionic
>
> navigate to **src -> theme -> varaiables.scss file**

you can find **$colors** variable by default there may be five colors

you can add your own custom colors

```
$colors: (
  primary:    #488aff,
  secondary:  #32db64,
  danger:     #f53d3d,
  light:      #f4f4f4,
  dark:       #222,
  basecolor:  #BA5B0D // add your own color here
);
```

And you can use this color in various components

```
<ion-header >
  <ion-navbar color="basecolor">
    <button ion-button menuToggle>
      <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
    </button>
    <ion-title> {{ company_name }} </ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
```

check the [doc](https://ionicframework.com/docs/theming/theming-your-app/) for more info

Comment: Hello thanks for replied I have to make it base on user input code color. or do you have any idea to complied code color varaiables.scss
$colors: (
  basecolor:  $baseColor // add my own varaiables
);
https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/14652
thanks

Comment: i think you can do it by dom reference of nav bar

Comment: I find the solution